# How to pass json object as parameter to java method(supplied as a jar i ExecuteScript) from groovy in Nifi?

Tags: json, groovy, apache-nifi

I am getting a json object in flow file which I need to pass to a java method which takes json object as parameter. I am doing this calling through groovy script by supplying java method jar in Module Directory property of ExecuteScript Processor. It would be nice if somebody helps me with groovy script. I went through the cookbook by on execute script processor which explains almost everything, in any way if you can help  Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=nifi+groovy+example

Answer (score 1):

the simplest groovy that reads flow content will look like this:

```
def ff = session.get()
if(!ff) return

def text = session.read(ff).withStream{ it.getText("UTF-8") }
//do here something with text...
session.transfer(ff, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the method signature you are trying to call? Building off daggett's answer, you can store the text content of the flow file (presumably a JSON object?) into a variable, then create a JsonSlurper to read the text into an Object and pass that into your method. The object is a POJO made up of arrays, maps, etc. that correspond to the JSON object. If your method takes a string and parses the object itself, then you won't need the JsonSlurper and can simply pass the string containing the flow file content into your method.

Comment: what should be the groovy script if my java method takes string which contains the flow file content ? @mattyb